# What are the names of default indicators (and of packages they belong to) in Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: indicator

How are they called? What packages do they belong to? It is useful for configuring them via dconf, reporting bugs and so on but hard to find out. I remember there was similar question for 11:04 but cannot find it.

These are the indicators on my system: 
[image: Indicators in my sessin]

There are ten, the last one on the left is Tomboy, the rest is more or less default (the second from the left is displayed only if more than one keybord layout is used). What are their names? And the names of their packages?

Comment: Tomboy, Keyboard layout, Message, battery, bluetooth, Network manager, volume, clock applet of gnome, what is left of me menu, power cog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From left to right

1. [Tomboy](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tomboy)
2. [Keyboard layout](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html) (gnome-settings-daemon)
3. [MessagingMenu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MessagingMenu) (indicator-messages)
4. Power (indicator-power)
5. [Bluetooth](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bluetooth) (gnome-bluetooth)
6. [Network manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager) *network-manager-gnome*
7. [Sound menu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoundMenu) (indicator-sound)
8. [Time and Date](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TimeAndDate) (indicator-datetime)
9. [MeMenu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MeMenu) (indicator-session)
10. [Session menu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SessionMenu) (indicator-session)

Comment: Thanks. That almost answers it. But upon reading the reply, I would like to know which packages are behind those indicators (after all, that is what one needs to know when reporting bugs).